# Find limits for functions of natural numbers

Tags: analysis, graph-theory

So I am dealing with some problems about random graphs where we find limits of functions of natural numbers. A simple example can be the limit of $\ln(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $n$ is the number of vertices of a graph. My concern is how do we intepret this type of limit? Can we view it as a special type of limits in the calculus setting, where we have the variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$? In particular, can we still apply tools from calculus (say the l'Hospital's rule) to find limits of $f(n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we know that $f(x)$ converges as $x \to \infty$, then it doesn't matter how we get there (we can take $ x_n = n$). But if we aren't sure there can be problems. For example $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin{n\pi x} = 0$, so if we know convergence "in $\mathbb{N}$" it doesn't necessarily buy us anything in the real sense. You aren't sampling all the possible sequences, in a sense.

So yes, if we know a limit exists, we can apply calculus tools. But if we aren't sure, we might get gobbledygook.